# How to preserve the offset while deserializing OffsetDateTime with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, java-time

In an incoming JSON, I have an ISO8601-compliant datetime field, containing zone offset. I'd like to preserve this offset, but unfortunately Jackson defaults to GMT/UTC while deserializing this field (what I understood from http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQDateHandling).

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class JacksonOffsetDateTimeTest {

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        objectMapper = Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json()
            .modules(new JavaTimeModule())
            .featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
            .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException {
        final String json = "{ \"date\": \"2000-01-01T12:00:00.000-04:00\" }";
        final JsonType instance = objectMapper.readValue(json, JsonType.class);

        assertEquals(ZoneOffset.ofHours(-4), instance.getDate().getOffset());
    }
}


public class JsonType {
    private OffsetDateTime date;

    // getter, setter
}
```

What I'm getting here is:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<-04:00> but was:<Z>
```

How can I make the returned OffsetDateTime to contain the original Offset?

I'm on Jackson 2.8.3.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Change your Object Mapper to this to disable the  ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE.

```
objectMapper = Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json()
            .modules(new JavaTimeModule())
            .featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE)
            .build();
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I've just figured this out on my own, after digging into Jackson internals.

Comment: Six years later, but my sincere thanks! It's weird that the default behavior is to throw away the offset, but at least there's a fix.